# ExtJS 4.2: ToolTips not wide enough to see contents

Tags: javascript, extjs

I've noticed since upgrading to ExtJS 4.2 that tooltips displayed when a textfield has an error in it are not wide enough to see the contents of the tooltip - they always seem to be 40px wide.

Here's a test case which shows the problem:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Field error tooltips</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext-4.2.0/resources/css/ext-all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-4.2.0/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    Ext.onReady(function(){

        var form = Ext.create("Ext.form.Panel",{
            title: 'My form',
            width: 300,
            height: 100,
            items: [
                {xtype: 'textfield', name: 'FIELD1', fieldLabel: 'Field 1', allowBlank: false}
            ],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above example if you click the field and then click out of it without typing anything, it shows a tooltip saying that it's not allowed to be blank. The tooltip is not wide enough to see the message unfortunately. Has anyone else come across this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys, but I found a solution on the sencha forum which seems to work:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?260106-Tooltips-on-forms-and-grid-are-not-resizing-to-the-size-of-the-text/page3#24

Specifically the following code at the beginning of the app:

```
delete Ext.tip.Tip.prototype.minWidth;
```

Comment: It's a bit hacky I know, but it looks like it does this trick!

Comment: Right at the top of my app.js file. In the example above, I would put it just after Ext.onReady

Comment: It works, thank you. But using MVC we need to put the code at the top of Viewport.js

Comment: Does not work for me. I use 4.2.1. and MVC and put it at top of Viewport.js. Still not working in Chrome and FF

Comment: It does not work for me either. I am trying IE9 and still have the tooltip cut off.

Answer (score 19):

this is o bug of extjs 4.2,
it work on firefox 19 but not in chrome 26

you should overide the css class for the tooltip:

```
.x-tip {
    width: auto !important;
}
.x-tip-body {
    width: auto !important;
}
.x-tip-body span {
    width: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this didn't seem to work for me. The width seems to be set directly in inline style, and these CSS rules don't seem to overrule the inline styles...

Comment: this helped me. delete Ext.tip.Tip.prototype.minWidth; didnt work for me although in a previous application, that seemed to have fixed the problem.

Comment: This worked for me on 4.2.1 for Firefox.  Deleting `Ext.tip.Tip.prototype.minWidth` didn't work for me.  Thanks

Comment: Beware of this, it will apply to all the tips inside the application. If you want it to be applied to only a few fields say a form field, then tailor it accordingly. Refer to @James answer below

Comment: this eventually fixed my problem. Im using Extjs4.2.1

Answer (score 4):

Sorry I can't be of much help, it is a known issue with 4.2.0 that will likely be fixed in their next release.  See: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?257201

As a temporary workaround, if you don't need dynamic sizing of the tip container, you can just override the CSS

```
.x-tip-form-invalid, .x-tip-body-form-invalid {
    width: 150px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks James, but I really need the tooltips to resize according the contents (up to a limit!)

Comment: Thanks! This works for me in `4.2.1` in Chrome and FF and IE. The other solutions don't work for me.

Comment: Thanks James, this worked for me, and it applies only to form related fields.

Answer (score 3):

Still looking at this now and then out of curiosity...

I tried comparing the the 4.1 and 4.2 sources some more. I think the problem is in the auto container layout somewhere. Between 4.1 and 4.2 A TON of stuff changed. So we can look through this.

hopefully it works out for some people.

```
if(Ext.isIE10) { 
      Ext.supports.Direct2DBug = true;
  }

  if(Ext.isChrome) {
      Ext.define('Ext.layout.container.AutoTip', {
        alias: ['layout.autotip'],
        extend: 'Ext.layout.container.Container',

        childEls: [
            'clearEl'
        ],

        renderTpl: [
            '{%this.renderBody(out,values)%}',

            '<div id="{ownerId}-clearEl" class="', Ext.baseCSSPrefix, 'clear" role="presentation"></div>'
        ],

        calculate: function(ownerContext) {
            var me = this,
                containerSize;

            if (!ownerContext.hasDomProp('containerChildrenDone')) {
                me.done = false;
            } else {

                containerSize = me.getContainerSize(ownerContext);
                if (!containerSize.gotAll) {
                    me.done = false;
                }

                me.calculateContentSize(ownerContext);
            }
        }
    });

    Ext.override(Ext.tip.Tip, {
        layout: {
            type: 'autotip'
        }
    });
}

Ext.QuickTips.init();
```

You can see more details [on this forum topic](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?260106-Tooltips-on-forms-and-grid-are-not-resizing-to-the-size-of-the-text&p=955886&viewfull=1#post955886).

Answer (score 3):

Deleting Ext.tip.Tip.prototype.minWidth doesn't fix the problem in all cases (on IE10) for me, and adding

```
if(Ext.isIE10) { 
      Ext.supports.Direct2DBug = true;
}
```

Fixes tooltips but causes other weird problems (toolbar button margins are sometimes affected!). The best solution I have seen is:

```
Ext.override(Ext.tip.QuickTip, {
        helperElId: 'ext-quicktips-tip-helper',
        initComponent: function ()
        {
            var me = this;


            me.target = me.target || Ext.getDoc();
            me.targets = me.targets || {};
            me.callParent();


            // new stuff
            me.on('move', function ()
            {
                var offset = me.hasCls('x-tip-form-invalid') ? 35 : 12,
                    helperEl = Ext.fly(me.helperElId) || Ext.fly(
                        Ext.DomHelper.createDom({
                            tag: 'div',
                            id: me.helperElId,
                            style: {
                                position: 'absolute',
                                left: '-1000px',
                                top: '-1000px',
                                'font-size': '12px',
                                'font-family': 'tahoma, arial, verdana, sans-serif'
                            }
                        }, Ext.getBody())
                    );

                if (me.html && (me.html !== helperEl.getHTML() || me.getWidth() !== (helperEl.dom.clientWidth + offset)))
                {
                    helperEl.update(me.html);
                    me.setWidth(Ext.Number.constrain(helperEl.dom.clientWidth + offset, me.minWidth, me.maxWidth));
                }
            }, this);
        }
    });
```

This seems to work on IE9 and 10, Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: This is the only solution that works for me (in Ext 4.2). Originally I tried deleting the Ext.tip.Tip.prototype.minWidth. This worked most of the time, but sometimes, for no apparent reason, the tooltips would suddenly become vertical. This override seems to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

An other not too bad solution was to add this CSS :

```
.x-border-box .x-tip, .x-border-box .x-tip * {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

But tooltips are a little too large.

I will try user826840's solution with the override of Ext.tip.QuickTip.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to override minimum width of QuickTip since field layout creates new QuickTip which does not rely on QuickTip singleton (contrary to the documentation).

```
Ext.override(Ext.tip.QuickTip,{
    minWidth: 200
});
```

Comment: Ext.apply(Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.getQuickTip(), {
            minWidth: 200
});

Answer (score 0):

Use `<br/>` tag to display a multi-lines tooltip can be sometimes useful to solve width problem.

```
const msg = 'bla bla...<br/>bla bla...'; // Here <br/> tag in html message.

Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
    target: component.id,
    html: msg
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are facing issue on tooltip EXTJS 4.2.1 in IE browser. You have to add the following line to your ASPX page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: I absolutely recommend to not change your doctype just for this mini-problem. It'll probably introduce tons of other layout problems. Try one of the other answers presented here.