# Making Ext Js Ext.Tip resizable

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have a UI tip component in my code, I want to make this component resizable

I am currently using Ext Js 3.2 library

Comment: Do you want to resize it programatically, or to make it possible for the user to resize it? What have you tried?

Comment: User should be able to change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind a [resizer](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Resizable) to it:

```
var resizer = new Ext.Resizable(tip.id, {
    handles: 'all',
    pinned: false
});

resizer.on('resize', function() {
    tip.syncShadow();
});
```

Unfortunately, it seems that the tip component has not been developed with arbitrary sizing in mind, so you'll have to hack the CSS...

Comment: syncShadow seems to be private member in ExtJS 3.5

Comment: That's true. I guess, you will have to get dirty hacking a tooltip this way. In fact, I don't know why you've decided to use a ToolTip for that usage, and in my opinion you'd better go with a BoxComponent or a Panel with custom styling.

Comment: Cant I use syncSize() in place of syncShadow ?

Comment: I wouldn't... I think `syncSize` is intended for auto sizing the component, and you're precisely trying to resize it manually. In the best case, it would just end up calling `syncShadow` itself, in the worst case it will conflict with your own resize.

Comment: Anyway, the answer to your question is to use `Ext.Resizable` and hack the Tip class and CSS like a madman until it supports proper resizing. The second part is just a pointer to get you started in this (probably hard) way...

Comment: I used the div class related to Tip and resized its children,

Comment: It works well in chrome and firefox, but doesnot work in IE .You think there is any specific reason ?

Answer (score 0):

See this to check your questions answer.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834689/extjs-4-2-tooltips-not-wide-enough-to-see-contents
```